# What could be the reason for an if- statement in an R loop to only consider the first condition of the loop?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I spent a few hours trying to figure out why this loop isn't working. It keeps on printing *'1'*. The dataset used contains combinations of the 4 variables, though it seems the unsuccessful loop covers the first one only:

```
data$newcolumn <- for (newcolumn in 1:nrow(data)) 
    {if(data$Male_exposure=="High" && data$Quality=="HighQ") {print(1)}
       if (data$Male_exposure=="High"&& data$Quality=="LowQ") {print(2)}
       if (data$Male_exposure=="Low"&& data$Quality=="HighQ") {print(3)}
       if (data$Male_exposure=="Low"&& data$Quality=="LowQ") {print(4)}}
```

Why could that be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `ifelse` here, which is already vectorized.  But, there is a potentially cleaner way of expressing your logic using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

data$newcolumn <- case_when(
    data$Male_exposure == "High" && data$Quality == "HighQ" ~ 1,
    data$Male_exposure == "High" && data$Quality == "LowQ"  ~ 2,
    data$Male_exposure == "Low"  && data$Quality == "HighQ" ~ 3,
    data$Male_exposure == "Low"  && data$Quality == "LowQ"  ~ 4
    TRUE ~ 5
)
```

If you really wanted to continue with your loop approach, then you would need to actually make use of the loop counter inside the loop's code:

```
data$newcolumn <- for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    if (data[i, "Male_exposure"] == "High" && data[i, "Quality"] == "HighQ") {
        print(1)
    }
    if (data[i, "Male_exposure"] == "High" && data[i, "Quality"] == "LowQ") {
        print(2)
    }
    if (data[i, "Male_exposure"] == "Low" && data[i, "Quality"] == "HighQ") {
        print(3)
    }
    if (data[i, "Male_exposure"] == "Low" && data[i, "Quality"] == "LowQ") {
        print(4)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, appreciate it!